# How to remove gap between line number and body in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Why there is a gap between line number and body. I am not using Distraction Free mode?

[image: There is image of space between line number and body]

Comment: *" I am not using Distraction Free mode"* But have you tried it (or Full Screen mode, perhaps)? If you did -- try restarting IDE then -- should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146089. Just restart the IDE to restore the tree layout